# Is casting possible in parameter expressions in OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++

I have a fairly simple bit of code in OMNET++ that takes one parameter from the user and uses it to decide several others

```
network ExampleNetwork
{
    parameters:
         int k;
         int variable = (k / 2);

    ...
}
```

This code will build correctly but when running gives the error message:

> 'Cannot evaluate parameter 'test'. Cannot cast 1 from type double to
>   integer (note: no implicit conversion from double to int)'

where '1' is the value of k/2.

It seems the way to fix this would be to explicitly cast the result of the expression to int but I cannot find any documentation that states how to do this in NED files.

Does anyone know how they are meant to be written?

I believe this was working on earlier versions of OMNET++. I'm now on version 5.4 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for answering with a simple "RTFM", but this is the most effective: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-functions:category-conversion

Since OMNeT++ 5.3, `double` values are no longer converted to `int` implicitly.

Use the `int` function, like this: `int variable = int(k / 2)`;