# Error: tcpip::Socket::recvAndCheck @ recv: peer shutdown

Tags: macos, omnet++, veins, sumo, plexe-veins

I am trying to run an example from the plexe-veins folder on my Mac OS High Sierra system, to my knowledge I have installed all necessary libs.

1. The only problem I have is with installing the `omnetpp__0.7-1.tar.gz` file. Some research online leads me to believe the version of R on my computer is unable to compile the file since the file is an older version. I have tried installing older versions but failed because of compatibility issues with my OS. I am at a complete dead-end with regards to that.
2. When I run the platooning example, the GUI opens up of and I am able to run the simulation for a few seconds until I get the error:

> (omnetpp::cDoubleParImpl)simulationDuration: Cannot cast from type
>   double to integer -- in module (SimplePlatooningApp)
>   scenario.node[0].appl (id=11), at t=1.01s, event #204 TRAPPING on the
>   exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true configuration option.
>   Is your debugger ready? ./run: line 2: 90810 Trace/BPT trap: 5
>   ../../run "$@"

The version of omnet I installed is omnet++-5.4 and I also followed the procedure from the manual which includes the "./configure" and "make" commands. I run the example by entering the dir in question and run: 
`./run -u Cmdenv -c Sinusoidal -r 2`

Comment: I am a little confused. Which OMNeT++ version did you install?

Comment: To be able to use `./run` from the command line, Veins needs to have been built from the command line (by running `./configure` and `make` in its root directory).

Comment: Which Plexe version are you running?

Comment: That should be plexe-2.0

Answer (score 2):

It appears my problem was multi-pronged. These are the steps I took to solve the problem:

- I followed the suggestions offered by Julian with regards to the version of Omnet++ I installed, I downgraded to Omnet++ 5.0
- I also noticed that I had a previously installed sumo (not plexe-sumo) on my system and thus it seemed to be running the simulation instead of plex-sumo. So I uninstalled it.
- There also seemed to be a problem with a static declaration of 'abs'followed by a non-static declaration which caused omnetpp_0.7.1.tar.gz to fail while compiling. I solved this issue by locating the stdlib.h file in xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/usr/include/v1 and commented out "inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY" (there should be a better fix).

I appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

The part of OMNeT is a casting error. This is due to OMNeT++ 5.4 which changed some internals on parameters and therefore is simply to new for Plexe 2.0. You have to use an older version like OMNeT 5.0 or 5.1 as this is what Plexe 2.0 was built upon.

Also see these posts:

- [Error in Veins tutorial simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366328/error-in-veins-tutorial-simulation)
- [Error while running example of the veins in the last step of the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967052/error-while-running-example-of-the-veins-in-the-last-step-of-the-installation)
- [Is casting possible in parameter expressions in OMNET++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875724/is-casting-possible-in-parameter-expressions-in-omnet)